# Should I use a framework (like Angular or React) or a view engine (like pug or handlebars)?

Tags: node.js, express, frameworks, frontend

I'm a beginner at Node and Express, so I might be wrong, but as from what I've learned, you should use one or another. So what do you think are the pros and cons of one and another? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you would want to build your application and what your use case is, also which coding style/syntax patterns appeal to you. If you're going for something like a web app/single page application, Pug is nice because you can generate elements dynamically. You can have a database full of different values, users, blog posts/comments and render those to the DOM using whatever style or layout you want by fetching them from the Database and rendering them to the page with Pug.

The nice thing about React is that there are things like React-Native, which will eventually let you bring over your JavaScript  code to mobile Android and iOS, so you can get a mobile app out quickly with your existing code base, instead of splitting it into 3 separate languages.

I haven't played around with angular too much, so I can't help you there